# ToolStripMenuItem not closing when a child ToolStripMenuItem is Clicked in a C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to have a ToolStripMenuItem not closing when I click a child control (in its DropDrowItems Collection)?

In my case, I have some ToolStripMenuItems that work as a check box. Actually, I implemented a radio behavior in some ToolStripMenuItems using their Check property. But I don't want the menu closing when I click any of them, because they aren't an action, they represent just options in the menu item.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   this.menuItem.DropDown.Closing += new ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler(DropDown_Closing); 

void DropDown_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    ((ToolStripDropDownMenu) sender).Invalidate();
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for [ToolStripDropDown.AutoClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.autoclose.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information:

- The Closing event exists on the **ContextMenuStrip** and the **ToolStripDropDown**.
- While designing with the designer, you have access to the **ContextMenuStrip** (the popup menu) and the ToolStripMenuItem (a submenu) objects, but not the **ToolStripDropDown** objects of the ToolStripMenuItem!
- That's why you must set the Closing event of the **ToolStripDropDown** objects yourself by code (see Zabulus answer).